# Как сказать блоку: занимай 45%, а если не тебе нужно больше места - уменьшайся

Tags: html, css, angular2, flexbox, layout

Используются `fxLayout` и `material2`. Нужно сделать респонсивную вёрстку, всё получилось за исключением небольшой мелочи. Есть ещё подвох, `fxLayout` постоянно перезатирает `css` для `flex`, `min-width`, `max-width`, `width`, поэтому в нём предусмотрена директива `[style]`, однако её не получиться использовать для размеров, кроме `xs`, `md`, `lg`, `xs`, `sm`. Например, хотел с помощью `media(min-width: 1103)`, поставить блоку `flex: 0 0 38%`, однако не работает. Ещё добавлю, что родная ширина прогресс баров, очень маленькая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание проблемы на скриншотах:

Вот тут хорошо бы задать 45%:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А здесь нужно 38%:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!-- Этот кусок кода, fxFlex.md="0 0 38%" -->
<md-card fxFlexOrder="3" [fxFlexOrder.md]="2" [fxFlexOrder.sm]="4" fxFlex.md="0 0 38%" fxFlex.sm="0 1 87%" fxFlex.xs="0 1 90%" [style.md]="{'max-width': '38%'}" [style.sm]="{'max-width': '87%'}">
  <job-summary-progress fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around" style="height: 100%" [progress]="progress"></job-summary-progress>
</md-card>
<!--Конец, дальше весь оригинальный код-->



<div class="job-dashboard-summary" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" fxLayoutAlign.sm="center space-between" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutWrap.md="no-wrap">
  <md-card fxFlex="1 1 23%" fxFlex.md="45%" fxFlexOrder="1" [style]="{'min-width': '478px'}" [style.sm]="{'min-width': '478px'}" [style.md]="{'min-width': '478px'}" [style.lg]="{'min-width': '478px'}" [style.xl]="{'min-width': '478px'}" fxFlex.xs="90%"
    fxFlex.sm="87%">
    <job-summary-costs [jobCosts]="jobCosts"></job-summary-costs>
  </md-card>
  <md-card fxFlexOrder="2" [fxFlexOrder.sm]="2" [fxFlexOrder.md]="3" fxFlex.md="45%" fxFlex.sm="0 1 41.5%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <job-summary-job [job]="job"></job-summary-job>
  </md-card>
  <md-card fxFlexOrder="3" [fxFlexOrder.md]="2" [fxFlexOrder.sm]="4" fxFlex.md="0 0 38%" fxFlex.sm="0 1 87%" fxFlex.xs="0 1 90%" [style.md]="{'max-width': '38%'}" [style.sm]="{'max-width': '87%'}">
    <job-summary-progress fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around" style="height: 100%" [progress]="progress"></job-summary-progress>
  </md-card>
  <md-card fxFlexOrder="4" [fxFlexOrder.sm]="3" [fxFlexOrder.md]="4" fxFlex.md="45%" fxFlex.sm="0 1 41.5%" fxFlex.xs="90%">
    <job-summary-phases [phases]="phases"></job-summary-phases>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужен экзоцист.

Comment: Сделайте код исполняемым. Чего 45%? чего 38%?

Comment: @kizoso от ширины родительского контейнера